# Deleting a user with ReactJS/Firebase SDK

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make an admin panel for my website which has a page to allow admins to delete users. The issue is, I have tried 2 different ways to delete a user using the Firebase SDK/React and I get similar errors for both methods.

**Method 1 (where `const app = firebase.initializeApp(...)`)**

```js
const auth = app.auth()
auth.deleteUser(uid)
```

Error:
`_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.auth.deleteUser is not a function`

**Method 2**

```js
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
getAuth().deleteUser(uid)
```

Error:
`_firebase_auth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.getAuth)(...).deleteUser is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete a user by their UID from the client-side SDK, as that would allow any user of your app to delete any other user's account by simply knowing their UID (which is quite common).

The client-side SDK can only [delete the currently signed-in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#web-version-8_11). To [delete a user by their UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) you will have to use the Admin SDK in a trusted environment (such as your dev machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run).